# ORACLE PL/SQL UPDATING PRICE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi everybody this is my very first post on StackOverFlow,

I have a table Places which have an attribute price.  I want to increment the price everyday starting from today's date for example until a given date then I should delete it. Actually I'm a beginner in PL/SQL so any help is welcome !

my tables:

```
create table Reservations
(
   numReservation       number(5) not null,
   numSeat            varchar(3) not null,
   numFlight              number(5) not null,
   numClient            number(5) not null,
   date_res             date,
   priceTotal            number(10),
   constraint pk_reservations primary key (numReservation),
    constraint fk_concerne foreign key (numFlight) references Flights (numFlight) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_effectueres foreign key (numClient) references Clients (numClient) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_res_place2 foreign key (numSeat) references Seats (numSeat) on delete cascade
);

create table Seats
(
   numSeat             varchar(3) not null,
   numAirp             number(5) not null,
   position             varchar(10) not null,
   class              varchar(10) not null,
   price                number(5) not null,
   constraint pk_places primary key (numSeat),
    constraint fk_contient foreign key (numAirp) references Airplanes (numAirp) on delete cascade,
    constraint seats_position check (position in ('Hublot','Centre','Couloir')),
    constraint seats_classe check (classe in ('Eco','First','Affaire'))
);
```

What I want to do is to update price of a seat every day automatically. For example the price of a seat is $23 to day tomorrow it should be $23.50 and so on, until a given date.

Comment: Please show us your existing code and explain which problem you are having with it.

Comment: Help us help you - share the table structure, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: Why do you have PL/SQL in your title and in the body of your post? Are you looking to do these updates specifically through PL/SQL? They can be done in plain SQL (which is by far the better way to do it).

Comment: Sorry i will edit my post !

Answer (score 0):

Is "Places" the same as "Reservations", or something else ?

As others have noted, to add $0.50 to a column is just a simple

```
update seats
set    price = price + 0.5
```

If you wanted that to be a PL/SQL routine, then its just a case of wrapping that in a block, eg

```
procedure BUMP_PRICE is
begin
  update seats
  set    price = price + 0.5;
end;
```

and if you wanted that to run automatically, then you could the Oracle scheduler to automatically execute that routine every day, for example:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job (
    job_name       => 'MY_JOB',
    job_type       => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action     => 'begin bump_price; end;',
    start_date     => systimestamp,
    repeat_interval=> 'freq=daily; byhour=0; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
    enabled        => true);
end;
```

but for future reference, we need to hear the "story" around your question, for example, some sample data and what you want the output to be etc. That gives a much better chance of helping you.

Comment: thank you @Connor McDonald ! thats exactly what i was searching for i didn't know how to launch a procedure  automatically. thank you so much again !